# What do you call the element in the orange box?

Tags: email, text, copywriting

[image]

Wondering what's this part is called in design. Also the string in the orange box is not included in the email content when you open the email. How this string is created? Generated automatically?  Written by UX writers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to the **[Pre header text](https://essenceofemail.com/blog/email-subject-line-and-preheader/)**

> In brief, a preheader is a text that comes after the subject line when an email is viewed in your inbox. It’s often used to give your email list a taste of what’s inside the body of your email.

Here's an example of a *hidden pre-header* once you open the email from the article:

[image]

Comment: +1 This is the official nomenclature to communicate it to email marketers.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

If the context is the UI/UX itself: It is called a "microcopy". And yes, you can learn about how to write it effectively by searching for the term "UX Writing". https://uxwritinghub.com/what-is-microcopy/

If the context is the real content of the email: it is called "lead paragraph" or just "lead". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_paragraph) It comes from the journalism. It is a short summary of the following text.

I hope it helped. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!